# Second Order ODE and integral of exponential divided by a polynomial

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, partial-fractions

My original question was

> Solve $$x^2y'' + 2y' - 2y = 0$$

First I noticed that $x^2+2x+2$ is a solution. Using order reduction, doing $y = v(x)(x^2+2x+2)$, I found that $$\int\frac{e^{2/x}}{(x^2+2x+2)^2}dx$$

Can someone help me in this part, please? The only method I found used complex numbers and the $Ei$ function, but I would like a solution in another way.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2y'' + 2y' - 2y = 0$$
$$x^2y'' \color{red}{+ 2xy'-2xy'}+2y' - 2y = 0$$
$$(x^2y')' -2(xy)'+2y'  = 0$$
$$x^2y' -2y(x-1)  = C_1$$
$$v' +\dfrac 2{x^2}v  = \dfrac {C_1}{x^4}$$
Where $v=\dfrac y {x^2}$:
This is a first order DE that you can easily solve with integrating factor $\mu=e^{-2/x}$:
$$(ve^{-2/x})'   = \dfrac {C_1e^{-2/x}}{x^4}$$
$$ve^{-2/x}   = C_1\int \dfrac {e^{-2/x}}{x^4}dx+C_2$$
For the integral substitute $u=-\dfrac 1x$:
$$\int \dfrac {e^{-2/x}}{x^4}dx= \int  {u^2e^{2u}}du$$
Integrate by part. You get the solution you already have:
$$y_1=C_1(x^2+2x+2)$$
The second solution should be :
$$y_2=C_2x^2e^{2/x}$$

Comment: Nice solution! What a good trick! Awesome. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @TassandroCavalcanteLeitão